# Powershell GUIs - Is there an Active Directory dialog box for selecting an OU? Like the FileOpenDialog?

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

Is there a class (possibly exposed through .NET) that allows you to kick off an active directory gui tree list?  I have an app where I'm iterating the top level OU structure of a domain and presenting the distinguished name in a dropdown in my PowerShell gui but a more elegant solution (IMO) would be to click a button and allow the user to select the level of the OU to run the program against.  Does anyone know what library/class/etc. I could use to accomplish this task in PowerShell?  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it isn't perfect but I modified a treeview to dynamically enumerate the local domain structure displaying distinguishedNames.  Now, this isn't perfect, but it works for what I need it for:

http://thepip3r.blogspot.com/2011/06/powershell-guis-active-directory.html

Answer (score 0):

It exists as COM object usable in C++ as explain in [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675899%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Multiple developers port it to .NET. I use [the one from a french code sharing named Codes-Sources](http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier_fullscreen.aspx?id=52023&f=WindowsFormsApplication1/DirectoryObjectPicker/Picker.cs&lang=en) and adapt it to my needs.

---

Edited

You can get [there](http://www.silogix.fr/developpement/outils/Ressources-PowerShell/Directory-Object-Picker-en-PowerShell.aspx) to use Microsoft Directory Object Picker in PowerShell.

Comment: It should be possible to Add-Type the C# code and then call it from your PowerShell script.

Comment: Yes, but it's a big bunch of code that's why I don't do it but it can be doable.

Comment: so i guess i'm missing it... copy the code out to a seondary file and then add-type the path to invoke it?

Comment: I make te assembly usable from PowerShell, I published it on my blog you'll find the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

kudos to Micah for this awesome solution from https://itmicah.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/active-directory-ou-picker-revisited/

(I have been previously criticized on stackoverflow for posting a link only but for this no alternative as this code exceeds the 30,000 characters allowed)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ITMicaH/Powershell-functions/master/Active-Directory/OUs/ChooseADOrganizationalUnit.ps1